# Add CSS class to mutiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tabs-links">
  <a href="http://localhost:5000/index#tabpanel1">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:5000/index#tabpanel2">Tab 2</a>
</div>

<div id="tabpanel1">Tab Panel 1</div>
<div id="tabpanel2">Tab Panel 2</div>
```

I need to find all A in "tabs-links", get the value after "#" and add the CSS class "inactive" to all tabs panels. So I have:

```
    var tabsLinks = $(".tabs-links").find("a");
    var tabsPanels = tabsLinks.map(function () { 
      return $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]) 
    });
```

1. How can I add the class "inactive" to all tabsPanels?
2. Is there a way to improve my code?

Comment: `$(".tabs").addClass('inactive')`?

Comment: I need to add the class to divTabs elements not to ".tabs a"

Comment: Where do you see that I added it to ".tabs a"?

Comment: Sorry, you are using ".tabs" and what I need is to apply it to divTabs

Comment: I updated my code to make it more clear. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: According to your example, tabsPanels are just ".tabs-links a", in which case `$(".tabs-links a").addClass('inactive')` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a class to those div tabs

```
<div class="tab-panel" id="tabpanel1">Tab Panel 1</div>
```

and then do

```
$(".tab-panel").addClass("inactive")
```

or if you want to do it your way just do

```
$(".tabs-links a").each(function () { 
    $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]).addClass("inactive");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hashes = [];
$.each($('.tabs-links a'), function(key, element) {
    hashes.push($(element).attr('href').split('#')[1]);
});
console.log(hashes);
```